# How to check div tag contains partial view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, load, partial-views, onload

As we know `window.onload` event will fire only when the page is completely loaded.

I want to perform some action when a `partial view` loaded completely into `div tag` 
how to check that? 
like : `$('divID').`*_*_ ??

Comment: From your syntax, I can tell you're already probably using jQuery, check out .ready() , if not, there are plenty of questions here on SO that suggest how to create it with native listeners

Comment: No I do not need to use ready(). Coz I want to check partial view is fully loaded in div tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like:

```
$('#divID').ajaxComplete(function(){
    // do something
});
```

That is of course providing I am correct in my assumption: that you are using both AJAX to populate the DIV and also the Unobtrusive Ajax library rather than the Microsoft MVC Ajax libraries.

If the Partial is simply rendered on page load, then $(document).ready(function(){}) will serve you well.